# how fix my app for two request url to server

Tags: tomcat

i want request to server 192.168.0.55:40081

but my app request http://192.168.0.55/192.168.0.55:40081

localhost address is 192.168.0.55

how to fix?

tomcat server.xml setting

`<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">`

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and show us the code that your app uses to make that request. You might also want to check how to build a [mcve]